# Swing (JComboBox) bug? printing dimension

Tags: java, swing, printing, jcombobox

I was examining the dimension of `JComboBox` (I don't know if presented with other Swing Object).

The problem is presented when dimensions are printed.
**Is it a bug?**

*Here my code:*

```
    JPanel jpPanelOut = new JPanel();
    jpPanelOut.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jpPanelOut.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpPanelOut, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    JPanel jpPanel = new JPanel();
    jpPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 26));

    Font inFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 10);
    JPanel jpPanel0 = new JPanel();
    jpPanel0.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpPanel0, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    JLabel jlLabel0 = new JLabel("this is a new text");
    jlLabel0.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    jlLabel0.setFont(inFont);

    JSlider jslSlider0 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 1000000000, 1);
    jslSlider0.setFont(inFont);

    JSpinner jspSpinner0 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 0, 1000000000, 1));
    jspSpinner0.setFont(inFont);

    JTextField jtfTextField0 = new JTextField("1234567890abcdef_gpqyTÑ",48);
    jtfTextField0.setFont(inFont);

    JComboBox jcbComboBox0 = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"Average"});
    jcbComboBox0.setFont(inFont);
    ((JLabel)jcbComboBox0.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);

    jpPanel0.add(jlLabel0);
    jpPanel0.add(jslSlider0);
    jpPanel0.add(jspSpinner0);
    jpPanel0.add(jtfTextField0);
    jpPanel0.add(jcbComboBox0);



    inFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 10);
    JPanel jpPanel1 = new JPanel();
    jpPanel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpPanel1, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    JLabel jlLabel1 = new JLabel("this is a new text");
    jlLabel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    jlLabel1.setFont(inFont);

    JSlider jslSlider1 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 1000000000, 1);
    jslSlider1.setFont(inFont);

    JSpinner jspSpinner1 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 0, 1000000000, 1));
    jspSpinner1.setFont(inFont);

    JTextField jtfTextField1 = new JTextField("1234567890abcdef_gpqyTÑ",48);
    jtfTextField1.setFont(inFont);

    JComboBox jcbComboBox1 = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"Average"});
    jcbComboBox1.setFont(inFont);
    ((JLabel)jcbComboBox1.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);

    jpPanel1.add(jlLabel1);
    jpPanel1.add(jslSlider1);
    jpPanel1.add(jspSpinner1);
    jpPanel1.add(jtfTextField1);
    jpPanel1.add(jcbComboBox1);

    System.out.println("Height:" 
        + " jtfTextField:" + jtfTextField1.getPreferredSize().getHeight() + "," 
        + jtfTextField1.getMinimumSize().getHeight()
        + " jlLabel:" + jlLabel1.getPreferredSize().getHeight() + "," 
        + jlLabel1.getMinimumSize().getHeight()
        + " jcbComboBox:" + jcbComboBox1.getPreferredSize().getHeight() + "," 
        + jcbComboBox1.getMinimumSize().getHeight()
        + " jslSlider:" + jslSlider1.getPreferredSize().getHeight() + "," 
        + jslSlider1.getMinimumSize().getHeight()
        + " jspSpinner:" + jspSpinner1.getPreferredSize().getHeight() + "," 
        + jspSpinner1.getMinimumSize().getHeight()
        );

    jpPanelOut.add(jpPanel);
    jpPanelOut.add(jpPanel0);
    jpPanelOut.add(jpPanel1);
```

But the dimension are changed!!!

[image]

Please Look:

The appereance (width) of JTextFields **Red Circle**

The appereance (text) of JComboBoxs **Green Line**

Complete Code

```
package myPackage;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
  private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
      jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
      jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGap(0, 220, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
      layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addContainerGap(739, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(jButton1)
        .addContainerGap())
      .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
      layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(jButton1)
        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addGap(0, 51, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
  }// </editor-fold>                        

  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JPanel jpPanelOut = new JPanel();
    jpPanelOut.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    jpPanelOut.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpPanelOut, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    JPanel jpPanel = new JPanel();
    jpPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 26));

    Font inFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 10);
    JPanel jpPanel0 = new JPanel();
    jpPanel0.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpPanel0, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    JLabel jlLabel0 = new JLabel("this is a new text");
    jlLabel0.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    jlLabel0.setFont(inFont);

    JSlider jslSlider0 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 1000000000, 1);
    jslSlider0.setFont(inFont);

    JSpinner jspSpinner0 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 0, 1000000000, 1));
    jspSpinner0.setFont(inFont);

    JTextField jtfTextField0 = new JTextField("1234567890abcdef_gpqyTÑ",48);
    jtfTextField0.setFont(inFont);

    JComboBox jcbComboBox0 = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"Average"});
    jcbComboBox0.setFont(inFont);
    ((JLabel)jcbComboBox0.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);

    jpPanel0.add(jlLabel0);
    jpPanel0.add(jslSlider0);
    jpPanel0.add(jspSpinner0);
    jpPanel0.add(jtfTextField0);
    jpPanel0.add(jcbComboBox0);



    inFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 10);
    JPanel jpPanel1 = new JPanel();
    jpPanel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpPanel1, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    JLabel jlLabel1 = new JLabel("this is a new text");
    jlLabel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    jlLabel1.setFont(inFont);

    JSlider jslSlider1 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 1000000000, 1);
    jslSlider1.setFont(inFont);

    JSpinner jspSpinner1 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 0, 1000000000, 1));
    jspSpinner1.setFont(inFont);

    JTextField jtfTextField1 = new JTextField("1234567890abcdef_gpqyTÑ",48);
    jtfTextField1.setFont(inFont);

    JComboBox jcbComboBox1 = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"Average"});
    jcbComboBox1.setFont(inFont);
    ((JLabel)jcbComboBox1.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);

    jpPanel1.add(jlLabel1);
    jpPanel1.add(jslSlider1);
    jpPanel1.add(jspSpinner1);
    jpPanel1.add(jtfTextField1);
    jpPanel1.add(jcbComboBox1);

    System.out.println("Height:" 
        + " jtfTextField:" + jtfTextField1.getPreferredSize().getHeight() + "," 
        + jtfTextField1.getMinimumSize().getHeight()
        + " jlLabel:" + jlLabel1.getPreferredSize().getHeight() + "," 
        + jlLabel1.getMinimumSize().getHeight()
        + " jcbComboBox:" + jcbComboBox1.getPreferredSize().getHeight() + "," 
        + jcbComboBox1.getMinimumSize().getHeight()
        + " jslSlider:" + jslSlider1.getPreferredSize().getHeight() + "," 
        + jslSlider1.getMinimumSize().getHeight()
        + " jspSpinner:" + jspSpinner1.getPreferredSize().getHeight() + "," 
        + jspSpinner1.getMinimumSize().getHeight()
        );

    jpPanelOut.add(jpPanel);
    jpPanelOut.add(jpPanel0);
    jpPanelOut.add(jpPanel1);
    jPanel1.removeAll();
    jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    jPanel1.add(jpPanelOut);
  }                                        


  public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
      for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
          javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
  private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
  private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
  // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: with the code provided the problem can be reproduced.  In fact with this code it is that the two lower panels are shown in the image supplied.  No more code is required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can't compile and test the code posted, so therefore I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: taking you 200000 points on StackOverflow and you can not test this code (which includes only JPanel, JComboBox, JLabel, JSlider, JTextField and JSpinner)? I do not believe you.

Comment: (1-) Correct, those 200k points means I understand how the forum is designed to work. You are the one asking for help. It is your responsibility to make it easy for us to help you. That is the purpose of the `SSCCE`.  Why should I (we) take the time to create a class, define all the variables needed to get the code to compile. You are not the only person I (we) help. I spend my time helping those how appreciate the help. Apparently so do others since nobody else has offered any advice. Good luck, maybe next time you will take the time to ask a proper question with a proper SSCCE.

Comment: I post all code reproducing the problem...

Comment: Well we had no way of knowing that you are using a GroupLayout based on your original code. That is why a proper SSCCE should always be posted otherwise you are just wasting our time. I never use an IDE to generate my layout code so I have no idea what the GroupLayout is doing. I suspect somewhere you have a hard coded size that the Group layout is using. I would suggest that you don't use the IDE to generate the code. Instead you could probably just use a JPanel with a FlowLayout. The FlowLayout will respect the preferred size of any component you add to the panel.

Comment: All code performed by button is the first code, except (    `jPanel1.removeAll();
    jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    jPanel1.add(jpPanelOut);`) the problem is presented when I use `System.out.println(...);` to see the dimensions.  - - - - - - - The difference between   `jpPanel0` and `jpPanel1` is to use `System.out.println(...);`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a better SSCCE by simplifying your actionListener code to more easily demonstrate the component that was causing the problem. A SSCCE should only contain the relevant code that demonstrates the problem.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JPanel jpPanelOut = new JPanel();
    jpPanelOut.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    jpPanelOut.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpPanelOut, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    JPanel jpPanel0 = new JPanel();
    JComboBox jcbComboBox0 = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"Average"});
    jpPanel0.add(jcbComboBox0);

    JPanel jpPanel1 = new JPanel();
    JComboBox jcbComboBox1 = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"Average"});
    jpPanel1.add(jcbComboBox1);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Height:"
                + " jcbComboBox:" + jcbComboBox1.getPreferredSize().getHeight() + ","
            );
        }
    });

    jpPanelOut.add(jpPanel0);
    jpPanelOut.add(jpPanel1);
    jPanel1.removeAll();
    jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    jPanel1.add(jpPanelOut);
}
```

So basically the problem is the System.out.println(...) executes on a separate Thread. All updates to a Swing component should be executed on the Event Dispatch Thread. So the `getPreferredSize()` method on the combobox is causing a change in the combo box outside the EDT which is somehow causing a problem.

One solution is to wrap the code in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater. Another solution is to move the System.out.println(...) statement to the end of the method. Both of these solution will allow the combo box to be realized properly on the EDT before the printing of the height.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this issue only occurs under `Nimbus(Synth)LookAndFeel`:

> **SynthArrowButtonUI**
>
> ```
> public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
>   SynthContext context = getContext(c);
>   Dimension dim = null;
>   if (context.getComponent().getName() == "ScrollBar.button") {
>     //...
>   }
>   if (dim == null) {
>     // For all other cases (including Spinner, ComboBox), we will
>     // fall back on the single ArrowButton.size value to create
>     // a square return value
>     int size = context.getStyle().getInt(context, "ArrowButton.size", 16);
>       dim = new Dimension(size, size);
>     }
> //...
> ```

**NimbusComboBoxSizeTest**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NimbusComboBoxSizeTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    String[] model = {"Average"};

    JPanel p0 = new JPanel();
    JComboBox<String> combo0 = new JComboBox<>(model);
    p0.add(combo0);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JComboBox<String> combo1 = new JComboBox<>(model);
    p1.add(combo1);

    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    box.add(p0);
    box.add(p1);

    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> System.out.println("combo0: " + combo0.getPreferredSize()));
    System.out.println("combo1: " + combo1.getPreferredSize());

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      try {
        for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo laf : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
          if ("Nimbus".equals(laf.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf.getClassName());
            UIDefaults d = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
            System.out.println("ArrowButton.size: " + d.getInt("ArrowButton.size"));
            System.out.println("ComboBox.arrowButton.size: " + d.getInt("ComboBox:\"ComboBox.arrowButton\".size"));
            d.put("ArrowButton.size", 19);
            //or: d.put("ComboBox:\"ComboBox.arrowButton\".size", 16);
          }
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new NimbusComboBoxSizeTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

- `ArrowButton.size: 16`
- `ComboBox.arrowButton.size: 19`
- `combo1: java.awt.Dimension[width=74,height=26]`
- `combo0: java.awt.Dimension[width=77,height=26]`